# Tabularx equations out of line

Tags: equations, tabularx

Can anyone tell me why the following two equations are out of line vertically? The one on the right drops down and I have no idea why!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, hyperref, amsthm, geometry, amsfonts, enumitem, mathtools, upgreek, multicol, tabularx}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{aoc}{Axiom of Choice}


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}

\allowdisplaybreaks


\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}XX@{}}
\begin{equation} \nonumber
\varphi(g)^{+}=\begin{cases}
    \varphi(g), & \text{if $\varphi(g)\geq 0$}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
&
\begin{equation} \nonumber
  \varphi(g)^{-}=\begin{cases}
    -\varphi(g), & \text{if $\varphi(g)\leq 0$}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I  With your code example used in standard document (`article`)I can't reproduce your problem. Both equation are vertical aligned.

Comment: @Zarko That makes this even more annoying! I have no idea what would be causing it :(

Comment: To see, what cause your problem, wee need a complete small document with your equation beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that we can see your document layout. I suspect, that the `\linewidth` is to short for both equation, but as I say, whithot complete document, I can only guess.

Comment: Make a copy of your original document, comment out some lines, recompile and see if the error persits. If so, continue commenting out lines untill you have a small example document that reproduces the alignment problem. You can edit your question and add this example document.

Comment: @leandriis I have added a complete document to the question, with all of my preamble in case something there is causing the problem

Comment: You are loading `geometry` but not really using it. Instead of `\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}` you may want to use `geometry` to set the page parameters. According to what I find this solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in `geometry` package. Instead that you use

```
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, hyperref, amsthm, geometry, amsfonts, enumitem, mathtools, upgreek, multicol, tabularx}
 ...
\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}
```

try to use the followine rearrangement of your preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}  % <--- you should add `margin`
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem*{aoc}{Axiom of Choice}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}   % had to be loaded last
```

With it the result is:

[image]

Comment: This is precisely the content on my [above comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527626/tabularx-equations-out-of-line#comment1334394_527626).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, ups, you are partly right. I didn't see your comment (it wasn't show up) when upload solution. Interestingly/strange, if I not defining `margin` at geometry, than result is the same as OP experienced.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit seems to be `\nonumber`, so I'd use the `equation*` environment.

*Unrelated*: needless to load `amsfonts` if you load `amssymb`, and `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, hyperref, amsthm, geometry, enumitem, mathtools, upgreek, multicol, tabularx}

\setlength{\textwidth}{15cm}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
\begin{equation*}
  \varphi(g)^{+}=\begin{cases}
    \varphi(g), & \text{if $\varphi(g)\geq 0$}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
&
\begin{equation*}
  \varphi(g)^{+}=\begin{cases}
    \varphi(g), & \text{if $\varphi(g)\geq 0$}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{tabularx}
\vskip 3ex

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
\begin{equation}\nonumber
  \varphi(g)^{+}=\begin{cases}
    \varphi(g), & \text{if $\varphi(g)\geq 0$}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
&
\begin{equation}\nonumber
  \varphi(g)^{+}=\begin{cases}
    \varphi(g), & \text{if $\varphi(g)\geq 0$}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]